# Tikz: using functions for calculaton x, y parts of the coordinate in the stream of path operations

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to write something like this?

```
\draw[dotted] (pi*0.5,sin(pi*0.5)) -- ++(10,0);
```

I would like to use the trigonometric functions when entering x, y-parts of the coordinates. I got Package Tikz error. It is incorrect syntax, or this method is not possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, put braces around your functions.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dotted] ({pi*0.5},{sin(90)}) -- ++(10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But use degrees otherwise you need to enter `<number> r` to indicate that they are radians. So the second coordinate is just `1.decimals` hence the sine is close to zero but not zero. See the manual for math operations.